# How to test simple Spring controller?

Tags: spring, testing, model-view-controller, controller

This is how my controller looks. What's the goal of testing it and how to do it?

@Controller
public class MainController {

```
@Autowired
private WeatherStateRepositoryDAO weatherStateRepositoryDAO;


@RequestMapping("/")
public String mainPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("list", weatherStateRepositoryDAO.findAll());
    return "index";
}
```

}

Comment: Have following Spring's Getting started guide - it has references to testing and it will answer the How https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/GreetingControllerTests.java

Answer (score 0):

Follow Spring's Getting started guide

[Spring Web Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content)

> How to do it

The guide has [sample](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/ApplicationTest.java) references to testing and it will answer this. Off course this is Hello world but you get the idea. Checkout the `greetings` test which ensures the contents of the HTML.

> Goal of testing

Like every piece of code the goal of the testing is to ensure your code is doing the right thing.

In your case you are serving HTML content so your goal should be to ensure ensure proper behavior which would include:-

1. Resource Path/URL leads to correct view.
    e.g. `.andExpect(view().name("index")`
2. Correct Attributes.
    e.g. `.andExpect(model().attribute(`
3. Correct contents
    e.g. `.andExpect(content().string(containsString("Get your greeting")))`
4. Most IMPORTANT are the edge cases
   If you throw exceptions do you get 200 or a different error code. Or what is the returned object.